# Magento 2 : Reformat Shipping Address in Review & Payments Section

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, review, address

I create `custom attribute` for shipping address, after finishing checkout I can see custom attribute below telephone number. I want to change address format to my preference. below is the example of address format which I got after filled shipping method:

[image: review and payments]

here's the code to add new custom attributes field:

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['subdistrict'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.subdistrict',
            'label' => 'District',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [
                'required-entry' => true,
            ],
            'sortOrder' => 71,
            'id' => 'subdistrict',
            'options' => [
                [
                    'value' => '',
                    'label' => 'Please Select Your Subistrict',
                ]
            ]
        ];
```